Flexible elements between min and max width with CSS grid?
I'm trying to achieve some particular behaviour with grid but I have a problem. I'm using grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 400px)); To my understanding it should flex between 260px and 400px - in other words, width of the element in grid should start at 260px, then expand to maximum of 400px as width of the viewport increases, and then when space allows for it, it should add another element into the row and shrink back all elements in the row to 260px, and then repeat the process...if that makes sense. Unfortunately all elements always stay at 400px all the time and never shrink to 260px. Is there a way to achieve what I want with grid but without to much complication?

Nope, the elements will be 400px unless the screen is less than that width, at which point they will shrink towards a min of 260px;

I think you want grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr)); and then set a max-width on the children - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLdwgzB

a in  minmax(a, b) is only setting a min-width: a; on the grid items, while always trying to make the grid cell b wide, that is, if the grid container allows for b.

@Paulie_D Thanks for your reply. I tried this already and they only reach 400px on lower viewport widths. The higher the viewport width is the whole grid mutates at increasingly lower element width, just about 300pand never reaching 400px. And so it does in your codepen when you inspect grid elements. Does it mean I have to either live with it or use JavaScript / media queries?

@connexo Is there a way to achieve what I want with css grid at all then? Or should I just try to love it or use some other approach? I'm not gonna lie, I like this one-liner and I tried to avoid using media queries or JavaScript.

Apparently you're after grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(260px, 400px));. So fill, not fit.

@connexo Unfortunately not. I tried that too before posting my question and I can't tell the difference between the two. Thanks nonetheless.
